# Nginx ingress controller failed to run

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to deploy nginx-ingress controller in my own server without load balancer and cloud provider. I did the following steps:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
```

Then, I created a cluster role named `nginx-ingress` for the serviceAccount.
My `nginx-controller-service.yaml`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
  externalIPs:
    - my-external-node-ip
```

And `nginx-ingress-controller.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.17
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

But, when I get the deployment status, it shows me:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
ingress-nginx   deployment.apps/default-http-backend       1/1     1            1           17m
ingress-nginx   deployment.apps/nginx-ingress-controller   0/1     0            0           17m
```

The controller is not available/not running.

What's going wrong here, how to get logs of that failed deployment?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188407/discussion-on-question-by-justinus-hermawan-nginx-ingress-controller-failed-to-r).

Comment: t's good that it worked but are you sure its good idea to have a range from 80 to 32767

Comment: Yes, for now. My infrastructure is small category not large scale.

Comment: Hi I added the answer, as the issue was due to missing service account, after that Nginx ingress was up and running. I also added a reference for further read to gain more detail about the SA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused due to **missing** service account.

```
58m Warning FailedCreate ReplicaSet Error creating: pods "nginx-ingress-controller-5b7f66f95f-" is forbidden: error looking up service account ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress: serviceaccount "nginx-ingress" not found
```

with the following command you can create the SA

`kubectl create serviceaccount my-service-account`

for further detail  [k8s-service-account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)

Answer (score -1):

remove the below entries from service manifest

```
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

```
  externalIPs:
    - my-external-node-ip
```

Comment: I use internal IP as my node host, if I don't add externalIPs, it won't work as expected and the external ip column will be empty.

Comment: can you share the logs from controller pod. and also the output from ( kubectl get svc ). i suppose the svc is not getting bound to external ip

Comment: if you cant get the logs from controller pod then share the output from ( kubectl describe po <controller-pod-name> )